# jni program memory leak

Tags: java, c, memory-leaks, java-native-interface

I write a java program which calls some jni APIs in a native libary. The native libary is also written by me. The jdk version is jdk1.7_0_75. From the result of "top" command, I find the memory used by the program keeps going up. I have used "pmap -d" to check the memory mapping and I found a entry in the result of "pmap -d" is quite suspicious. Here is the entry:

```
00002b3373f63000  162388 rw--- 00002b3373f63000 000:00000   [ anon ]
```

The value of the second column keeps going up and always goes up by 4k each time I execute the "pmap -d" command. So how should I pinpoint the reason for this memory leak problem? Is it caused by the native code?

Comment: "Is it caused by the native code?" How can we know since there is no code. We can help you find the issue, but we need to know your code to investigate.

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire, the native code is too long, two cpp files. I don't know which line of the code could probably cause the problem. How should I show my code to you?

Comment: Chances are you don't need all of your code to demonstrate the problem. You need to narrow it down, and you may find the issue yourself while doing so.

Comment: Alternatively, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33334126/how-to-find-memory-leaks-in-java-jni-c-process, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8450792/java-performance-tuning-jni-memory-leak, https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/troubleshoot/memleaks005.html